# SQL Server Update Query does not use Index

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

I have a update query that runs slow (see first query below).  I have an index created on the table PhoneStatus and column PhoneID that is named IX_PhoneStatus_PhoneID.  The Table PhoneStatus contains 20 million records.  When I run the following query, the index is not used and a Clustered Index Scan is used and in-turn the update runs slow.

```
UPDATE PhoneStatus    
SET RecordEndDate = GETDATE()    
WHERE PhoneID = 126
```

If I execute the following query, which includes the new FROM, I still have the same problem with the index not used.

```
UPDATE PhoneStatus    
SET RecordEndDate = GETDATE()   
FROM Cust_Profile.PhoneStatus     
WHERE PhoneID = 126
```

But if I add the HINT to force the use of the index on the FROM it works correctly, and an Index Seek is used.

```
UPDATE PhoneStatus     
SET RecordEndDate = GETDATE()   
FROM Cust_Profile.PhoneStatus WITH(INDEX(IX_PhoneStatus_PhoneID))   
WHERE PhoneID = 126
```

Does anyone know why the first query would not use the Index?

**Update**

In the table of 20 million records, each phoneID could show up 10 times at the most

BarDev

Comment: Having indexes does not ensure that they are used.

Comment: thanks for doing test, have removed my answer as red herring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How many distinct PhoneIDs are in the 20M table? If the condition `where PhoneID=126` is not selective enough, you may be hitting the index [tipping point](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/The-Tipping-Point.aspx). If this query and access condition is very frequent, PhoneID is a good candidate for a clustered index leftmost key.

Comment: Quick comment about a clustered index.  With 20 million rows, if you insert data and the table has a clustered index, you may see a reasonable delay whilst the table re-organises itself to reflect the clustered index.

Comment: The PhoneID is very unique. In the table of 20 million records, each phoneID could show up 10 times at the most.

Comment: You can use the tips from this post to understand what rules are being applied that result in the wrong plan: see http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/07/31/inside-the-optimiser-constructing-a-plan-part-3.aspx

Comment: I went back and looked at the query again and noticed that the problem was only occurring in UAT.  Production seems to be running fine.  Also UAT has a very small set of data.   So I believe the first query does not use the Index because of the limited number of rows in UAT.  I will test this theory and put more records in UAT to test this scenario.

Comment: @BarDev: you mean very selective?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Is an index seek always better or faster than an index scan?](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/is-an-index-scan-always-better-or-faster)
Sometimes a seek and a scan will be the exact same.

An index might be disregarded because your stats could be stale or the `selectivity` of the index is so low that SQL Server thinks a scan will be better

Turn on stats and see if there are any differences between the query with and without a seek

```
SET STATISTICS io ON
UPDATE PhoneStatus
SET RecordEndDate = GETDATE()
WHERE PhoneID = 126


UPDATE PhoneStatus
SET RecordEndDate = GETDATE()
FROM Cust_Profile.PhoneStatus WITH(INDEX(IX_PhoneStatus_PhoneID))
WHERE PhoneID = 126
```

Now look at the reads that came back

Comment: PhoneStatus is the name of his table, not column. So I don't think this is not his case.

Comment: Would that be the case, I think the order of the index is OK, if it was in the wrong order even a hint wouldn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Pablo is correct, SQL Server will use an index only if it thinks this will run the query more efficiently.  But with 20 million rows it should have known to use the index.  I would imagine that you simply need to update statistics on the database.

Form more information, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260645(SQL.80).aspx.

Answer (score 1):

SQLServer (or any other SQL Server product for that matter) if not forced to use any index at all. It will use it, if it thinks will help running the query more efficiently.

So, in your case, SQLServer is thinking that it doesn't need using `IX_PhoneStatus_PhoneID` and by using its clustered index might get better results. It might be wrong though, that's what index hints are for: letting the Server know it would do a better job by using other index.

If your table was recently created and populated, it might be the case that statistics are somewhat outdated. So you might want to force a [statistic update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

To restate:

- You have table PhoneStatus
- With a clustered index
- And a non-clustered index on columns PhoneStatus and PhoneId, **in that order**
- You are issuing an update with "...WHERE PhoneId = 126"
- There are 20 million rows in the table (i.e. it's big and then some)

SQL will take your query and try to figure out how to do the work without working over
the whole table. For your non-clustered index, the data might look like:

```
PhoneStatus  PhoneID
  A            124
  A            125
  A            126
  B            127
  C            128
  C            129
  C            130
 etc.
```

The thing is, SQL will check the first column first, *before* it checks the value
of the second column. As the first column is not specified in the update, SQL
cannot "shortcut" through the index search tree to the relevant entries, and so will have to scan the entire table. (No, SQL is not clever enough to say "eh, I'll just check
the second column first", and yes, they're right to have done it that way.)

Since the non-clustered index won't make the query faster, it defaults to a table
scan -- and since there is a clustered index, that means it instead becomse a clustered index scan. (If the clustered index is on PhoneId, then you'd have optimal performance on your query, but I'm guessing that's not the case here.)

When you use the hint, it forces the use the non-clustered index, and that will be faster
than the full table scan *if* the table has a lot more columns than the index (which
essentially has only the two), because there'd be that much less data to sift through.

Comment: The non-cluster index only includes PhoneID.